# WCF and IIS performance spawning thousands of tasks using Task Parallel library

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, iis, asynchronous

My scenario:

A user login triggers a WCF-server which kicks off 20 [async-tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx). Each separate task (named job in code) is calling external SOAP-services. So for 1 000 simultaneous users logging in, it means 20 000 async tasks. Now we must call the services in batches (due to external limitations), to fetch paged data - however we are allowed to do it in parallel. So every one of the 20 tasks spawns 10 tasks of its own, which would mean 400 tasks per individual login - 400 000 tasks for 1 000 simultaneous logins.

My two questions:

1. **How would this impact our IIS and server performance?** From what I understand the tasks would be queued up and run in parallell if possible - are there any limits on recommended number of tasks?
2. **Am I using the right approach in creating these tasks?** Are they running truly `async` (except for the `WaitAll`)? See code below:

Create the tasks for each service to be called

```
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => job.Fetch());
}
```

The Job-class called above:

```
public async void Fetch()
{
    var batchList = await FetchBatches();
    //saves list to database
    MergeAndSaveBatchList(batchList);
}

private async Task<BatchResult> FetchBatches()
{
    var taskList = new List<Task<BatchResult>>();
    foreach (var batch in _batchesList)
    {
        //this is calling the external services
        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => batch.Fetch()));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    return taskList.Select(tl => tl.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of simple maths:

All Windows OS products since Windows XP use the IANA suggested range for dynamic/ephemeral ports.

Every TCP/IP connection requires an ephemeral port to receive the response. When the connection is done, it is held in `TIME_WAIT` state for 120 seconds before being freed up for reuse.

The IANA range of ephemeral ports is 49152 to 65535, for a total of 16383 epehmeral ports.

This means that under *optimal* conditions, your server can process 16383 connections every two minutes.

Because of HTTP connection pooling, there might not be a direct correlation between requests and connections, but I'd be extremely worried that an architecture that requires so many requests would result in [port exhaustion](https://serverfault.com/questions/453576/is-tcp-port-exhaustion-real).

Now, if you're making all the requests to the same service, you'll be up against a different limit... The connection limit for HTTP requests to the same host, which defaults to 10 on a server. When you go over this limit, stuff is going to get queued... This will result in unacceptable latency when you queue up thousands of requests to the same host. You can [fiddle with the limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but set it too high, and the remote server will probably deny your requests.

Can't you reduce the number of requests required in your architecture? The figures you quote are really rather high.

Comment: Thanks @spender! It seems I need to call the services synchronously, rather than async to get this working and scaling? Unfourtunately I cannot  affect how the external services work, only my way in doing it. And my goal is to download all data from the services in the shortest amount of time possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll essentially be performing a denial of service attack on your own server, there's not a chance for a single server to make it through that, to handle that you'll need multiple servers behind a load balancer.

Remember there's only so much work your CPU can pull off, and from your code you're I can tell you now that you're misusing the `async` feature, in this context, the reason for using `async` is to actually free up IIS threads so that they can serve other clients whilst your long running call completes in the background... the long-running call would be queued until a thread from the thread pool is free to serve it, but there's only so much work that you can queue before it goes kaput because those work items are stored in memory.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, the code above is running inside the same WCF, so I am not calling my own service many times, if that is what you mean by DDOS-attack on my own server? I renamed the class-name in the code sample.

What approach would you take for this scenario, if not using tasks? Calling the service syncronously would take too much time. Cheers!

Comment: Essentially what you're attempting to do is collect all  the users requests and then make a single batched call for each service right?

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear! The scenario is: 1 user logs in, WCF will fetch users data from 20 external services. All services needs to be called ten times to get all the data needed. This is happening for each user.

Comment: One idea would be to have a separate process running internally for each external service, these processes won't be triggered by the client, but instead be working 24 / 7.  and would cache the clients details on a database / storage solution of your choice where your WCF service could connect to and grab the users details. This way you would keep things scalable, and you would also remove the single point of failure.

Comment: Unfourtunately there is too much data to be able to pre-fetch it for caching. It must also be instantly up to date. So somehow I need to call all the services and get it all down.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't change the architecture of your application, and still be required to download data for your user, you still can use the `async` tasks, but you should chain them for each user you have, so at the same time there will be only one request per user but the work will be run asynchroniously, which will provide the ability to use all the system resources.

I think that code you have should be looking something like this:

```
public async void Fetch()
{
    var batchList = await FetchBatches();
    MergeAndSaveBatchList(batchList); //saves list to database
}
```

`async/await` version

```
private async Task<BatchResult> FetchBatches()
{
    var result = new List<BatchResult>();
    foreach (var batch in _batchesList)
    {
        result.Add(await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => batch.Fetch())); //this is calling the external services
    }
    return result;
}
```

Aggregate all tasks with [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx)

```
private async Task<BatchResult> FetchBatches()
{
    var result = new List<BatchResult>();
    var taskList = new List<Task<BatchResult>>();
    for (var i = 0; i < _batchesList.Count; ++i)
    {
        var localI = i;
        var batch = _batchesList[localI];
        taskList.Add(new Task(() => batch.Fetch())); //this is calling the external services
        if (localI < _batchesList.Count - 1)
        {
            taskList[localI].ContinueWith(t => 
            {
                // handle Exception here
                result.Add(t.Result);
                taskList[localI + 1].Start();
            });
        }
    }
    if (_batchesList.Count > 0)
    {
        await taskList[0];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. Let me try it out and get back to you. (I guess you mean _Aggregate all tasks with `Task.ContinueWith`_ and not `Task.Create`.

Comment: `await taskList[0]` will only await that task, and not wait for the other chained by ContinueWith unfourtunately. But it's a good start to build from!

Comment: You can try wrap the tasks into one parent task then. Didn't investigate deeply, but this shall work.

Comment: @cederlof [Good Article about child tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx)